# flutter_vlc_player lag when calling mediaPlayer.stop() on android native

Tags: flutter, dart, libvlc, flutter-video-player, vlc-android

I'm using [flutter_vlc_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player) for video playback on Android and ios.

When I dispose the player controller, it cause jank for a few frames.
When I debug the native android code, I see that `mediaPlayer.stop()` in `void dispose()` took about 40ms to complete, causing the jank. I used the player inside PageView and dispose the controller in the middle of page transition, so the jank is noticeable.

Is there a solution or workaround to make the ui look smooth?